# Tensorflow Serving REST API Throwing error

Tags: python, rest, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have built a very simple classification model for IRIS dataset in tensorflow version '1.10.0'. The code runs fine in jupyter notebook. I'm trying to deploy and serve through tensorflow serving using docker. Though docker starts, I'm unable to get the good result. Tensorflow Serving is bit new to me. Command I use and error output I get are as follows -

```
curl -d '{"instances": [1.0, 2.0, 5.0,4.2]}'   -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/irismodel:predict

{ "error": "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor \'y\' with dtype int32\n\t [[{{node y}} = Placeholder[_output_shapes=[<unknown>], dtype=DT_INT32, shape=<unknown>, _device=\"/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0\"]()]]" }
```

The complete code for training and saving the model is as follows. Please note that I'm using object obtained from saved_model.simple_save. As there are no model versions created, I simply create a folder named "1", and move content there.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('/my/path/iris.csv', delimiter=',',skip_header =1)

my_data[149,:]
array([5.9, 3. , 5.1, 1.8, 2. ])

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

n_inputs = 4  # MNIST
n_hidden1 = 3
n_hidden2 = 2
n_outputs = 3

def reset_graph(seed=42):
  tf.reset_default_graph()
  tf.set_random_seed(seed)
  np.random.seed(seed)

reset_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=(None), name="y")

hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden1, name="hidden1",activation=tf.nn.relu)
hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, n_hidden2, name="hidden2",activation=tf.nn.relu)
logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, n_outputs, name="outputs")

xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")

learning_rate = 0.01

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

arr = np.arange(150)
np.random.shuffle(arr)

my_data = my_data.reshape((150,5))
my_data = my_data[arr]

X_train = my_data[0:120,0:4]
X_test = my_data[120:150,0:4]
y_train = my_data[0:120,4].astype("int32")
y_test = my_data[120:150,4].astype("int32")

cursor = 0
def next_batch(X_train,y_train,batch_size):
   global cursor
   indices = np.arange(cursor,cursor+batch_size)
   cursor = cursor + batch_size
   return X_train[indices],y_train[indices]


from tensorflow import saved_model

n_epochs = 50
batch_size = 20
with tf.Session() as sess:
   init.run()
   for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        cursor = 0
        for iteration in range(X_train.shape[0] // batch_size):
            X_batch, y_batch = next_batch(X_train,y_train,batch_size)
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch.astype("int32")})
        acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch.astype("int32")})
        acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_test, y: y_test.astype("int32")})
        print(epoch, "Train accuracy:", acc_train, "Test accuracy:", acc_test)

   save_path = saver.save(sess, "./my_model_final.ckpt")
   saved_model.simple_save(sess,
        "/home/modelpath/imodel",
        inputs={"X": X},
        outputs={"y": y})
```

Even when I submit through Postman, I get similar error. I think I may be doing some mistake in datatype, but not sure. 
Another source of error might be the way I'm sending API request. 
Any pointers will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced your error and could resolve the issue. replace `y` in the last line of the code with `tf.dtypes.cast(np.argmax(logits), dtype = "int32", name = 'y_pred')`

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
   init.run()
   for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        cursor = 0
        for iteration in range(X_train.shape[0] // batch_size):
            X_batch, y_batch = next_batch(X_train,y_train,batch_size)
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch.astype("int32")})
        acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch.astype("int32")})
        acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_test, y: y_test.astype("int32")})
        print(epoch, "Train accuracy:", acc_train, "Test accuracy:", acc_test)

   Predicted_Output = tf.dtypes.cast(np.argmax(logits), dtype = "int32", name = 'y_pred')
   save_path = saver.save(sess, "./my_model_final.ckpt")   
   saved_model.simple_save(sess, "IRIS_Data_Export", inputs={"X": X}, outputs={"y": Predicted_Output})
```

Output is as shown below:

```
{
    "outputs": 0
}
```